# $getJSON returning a blank json on asynchronous call

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs, getjson

Hi below is my code in which I am loading some contents retrieved from server via `$getJSON` call into a tab using Jquery UI tabs. Now my problem is when I used asynchronous call its returning blank value so I used sync calls. Now its recommended not to use sync calls with AJAX also I need to show a loading message before tab contents are loaded. With sync call browser gets frozen and nothing is displayed.Below is the code:

```
var menuId=id;
    var id="tabs-" + id;
    var li=$('<li><a href="#'+ id +'">'+tabText+'</a><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span></li>');
    $(".ui-tabs-nav").append(li);
    $('#tabs').append( "<div id='" + id + "'><p><center><u>" + tabText + "</u></center></p></div>" );
if (applicationName=='SS'){
        var heading="";
        var data="";
        $('#'+id).append('<div id="SysStatus"></div>');
        $("#SysStatus").append('<table id="SysStatusTable" border="1"></table>');
        $("#SysStatus").hide();
        //Set async off to retrieve data from ajax synchronously
        $.ajaxSetup({async: false});
        $.getJSON('execSystemStatus.action', function(json) {

            //do something

        });
        $("#SysStatus").show();
    }
$('#tabs').tabs().tabs( "refresh" );

    $('#tabs').tabs().tabs( "option", "active", -1 );
```

Please suggest! How should I proceed to make async calls work appropriately or if there is some work around to show loading message with sync calls.

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Instead go for [**`callbacks in getJSON`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) like below which is widely suggested.

```
$.getJSON('execSystemStatus.action', function(json) {
    //do something
})
  .done(function() {
    console.log( "second success" );
  });
```